# How to make LED bar graphs to measure intensity

Tags: led, audio, operational-amplifier

I'm working with [this design](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2126272%20Schematic.pdf).

I would like to make those LEDs into LED bar graphs that will show the intensity. For example, I want a song with a loud base to make the bar graph shoot up to the top. The bars of the LED bar graph I would like to just be individual LEDs. I was getting the effect with an arduino but I was hoping there was easier way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LM3914 / LM3915 / LM3916  will do this job directly. There are other ICs that will do similarly. Search for "bar graph driver".

[image]

These will interface more or less directly in place of the 2N3904 transistors in your circuit. (Just as the SSR's would that I provided references to yesterday). Some minor component changes may be needed.

- LM3914 - linear
- LM3915 - log response
- LM3916 - "extended logarithmic" VU meter type display.

[NatSemi product page](http://www.national.com/mpf/LM/LM3916.html#Overview)

Also lists I^2C only (not analog input) LP3944, low voltage, 8 LEDs. LP3943, low voltage , 16 LEDs.

**Datasheets:**

- [LM3914](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM3914.pdf)
- [LM3915](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM3915.pdf)
- [LM3916](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM3916.pdf)

[IIC only - LP3943 product page](http://www.national.com/pf/LP/LP3943.html)

**Pricing** - Digikey, in stock

- [LM3914 pricing](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?[Detail&name=LM3914N-1-ND)
- [LM3915 pricing](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?[Detail&name=LM3914N-1-ND)
- [LM3916 pricing](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=LM3916N-1-ND)

Note below - display can be a bar or individual dot at selected level.

Edited relevant parts from LM3914 overview. Others similar

- Drives LEDs, LCDs or vacuum fluorescents
- Bar or dot display mode externally selectable by user
- Expandable to displays of 100 steps
- Internal voltage reference from 1.2V to 12V
- Operates with single supply of less than 3V
- Inputs operate down to ground
- Output current programmable from 2 mA to 30 mA
- Input withstands ±35V without damage or false outputs
- LED driver outputs are current regulated, open-collectors
- Outputs can interface with TTL or CMOS logic
- The internal 10-step divider is floating and can be
  referenced to a wide range of voltage

Answer (score 0):

There are easy to use integrated solutions like the [LM3914](http://www.national.com/mpf/LM/LM3914.html) If you look at it's block diagram inside the datasheet you'll see the basic idea. A Single voltage reference, a resistor ladder and one opamp (used as a comparator) per output.

Comment: Why do you say "opamp used as comparator" instead of "comparator"? They might well be real comparators, the symbol is the same.